# Laggy / delayed realm

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

I started a new Minecraft realm, I uploaded my single player world, that I had played for like 2 days. It does not have a lot of animals in it, maybe 40 total, and a decent farm, but it is so laggy and delayed, like I am playing cross server, I know it isn't my internet or PS5, I haven't had any other lag issues on any other game - including games I play across servers.

Comment: please add more details to the world you have uploaded.

Comment: Think of a standard Minecraft world, the only thing I’ve changed is made it so I keep my inventory on so I don’t lose me stuff when I die, I don’t know what other details to add, I don’t mess around with any settings what so ever, legit just made a new world, wanted my friends to be able to play while I was offline, so I started a realm up, that’s all I can say.